# Prepared Statement Return Get Results & Count

Tags: php, mysql, count, prepared-statement

I am trying to get both the results of my query and the row count wihtout having to make two trips the the DB if possible. I am using prepared statements in a procedural way. My code is as follows:

```
 $dbd = mysqli_stmt_init($dbconnection);
 if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($dbd, "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE First_Name = ?" )) {
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($dbd, "s", $val1);
 if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($dbd)) {
            echo "Execute Error: " . mysqli_error($dbconnection);
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    } else {
        echo "Prep Error: " . mysqli_error($dbconnection);
    }

    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($dbd);
```

So the above code works just fine and returns my results. What I want to do now is get the row count using this same statement but i don't want to have to write a brand new prepared statement. If I writer a separate prepared statement and use store_results and num_rows I get the row count but that would force me to have to write an entire new block of code and trip to db. I am trying to do something as follows but It throws and error:

```
 $dbd = mysqli_stmt_init($dbconnection);
     if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($dbd, "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE First_Name = ?" )) {
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($dbd, "s", $val1);
     if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($dbd)) {
                echo "Execute Error: " . mysqli_error($dbconnection);
            } else {
                //do nothing
            }
        } else {
            echo "Prep Error: " . mysqli_error($dbconnection);
        }

        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($dbd);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($dbd);
        $rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($dbd);
```

The throws and error as if i can't run both get results and store results using the same prepared statement. Im simply trying to keep my code compact and reuse as much as possible. If i break the above out into two separat prepared statements it works fine, Im just wondering there is a way to just add a line or two to my existing statement and get the row count. Or do i have to write an entire new block of code with new stmt_init, stmt_prepare, bind_param, execute, etc...

Comment: try this - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (and reformatted it a bit), but I can't get it to work when I use both store_result() and get_result(). I can only use store_result then bind_result().

So the alternative is to fetch all the rows and then count them:

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE First_Name = ?";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($dbconnection);
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,  $sql) === false) {
    trigger_error("Prep Error: " . mysqli_error($dbconnection));
    return 1;
}
if (mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $val1) === false) {
    trigger_error("Bind Error: " . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
    return 1;
}
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) === false) {
    trigger_error("Execute Error: " . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
    return 1;
}
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$num_rows = count($rows);
print "$num_rows rows\n";

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

In my opinion, PDO is much easier:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test", "xxxx", "xxxxxxxx");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE First_Name = ?";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$val1]);

$num_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
print "$num_rows rows\n";

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```